# Are tag wiki edits put into the standard Suggested edits review queue?

Tags: support, tagging, peer-review

I proposed 5 days ago an edit to a tag wiki that had no excerpt. I was curious to see if those kind of edits went to the Suggested edits review queue as normal question/answer edits so I looked at the numbers of posts in that queue and never saw it increment following my suggestion (which correctly appears as *suggested* in my profile under *All actions>Suggestions* tough without other details).

I would gladly improve it if something's wrong with it.

Comment: aside - edit has been approved now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it enters the normal Suggested Edits queue, although only people with 5k+ reputation can review it.

The number of items that you see in the suggested edits queue is personalized. It will change depending on how many of the edits *you can review*, even if there are other items waiting in the queue that you can't review. This includes edits that you've suggested yourself, tag wiki edits for those with under 5k reputation, and items that you've already reviewed.

The default view if you can't access the queue yourself shows the number of items available for users with 2k+ reputation, AFAIK.